# What could be cause of allocate failing with a SIGBUS

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, solaris, heap-memory

I am getting a runtime SIGBUS with the call stack showing as below:

```
 --- called from signal handler with signal 10 (SIGBUS) ---
 001279b8 allocate__t24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (20, 20, 2fa3c0, 32, 0, 0
) + a4
 00117380 __nw__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0_3RepUiUi (10, 10, 838e00, 0, 0, 0) + 14
 001173c0 create__Q2t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_all
oc_template2b0i0_3RepUi (9, 9, 838e00, 9, 0, 0) + 24
 00117784 replace__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_allo
c_template2b0i0UiUiPCcUi (fbf7f758, 0, ffffffff, fcbf40c2, 9, 80808080) + 114
 0012b988 assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCcUi (fbf7f758, fcbf40c2, 9, ffffffff, ffffffff, 20) + 24
 0012a35c assign__t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc
_template2b0i0PCc (fbf7f758, fcbf40c2, 90, b0, 1ff0, 0) + 24
 00127170 __t12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_templ
ate2b0i0PCc (fbf7f758, fcbf40c2, fcbf40b8, 1c00, 9, 7c) + 28
```

What could be the cause?
Stack overflow? or no more space on heap?

Comment: This is almost certainly a sign of an invalid deletion some time before the allocation that crashes with sigbus. Run through valgrind to see what is happening.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not necessarily true on Solaris/SPARC. It's also quite easy to get a `SIGBUS` on Solaris/SPARC by violating strict aliasing.  That tends to happen quite a bit with x86-experienced programmers, as SPARC has actual alignment restrictions that x86 doesn't have.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You wouldn't get these inside a call to an allocator, though.

Comment: Most likely, this is a corrupt heap. You should like your application with some debug version of malloc and see what happens.

Comment: No need to try to use Valgrind.  The Studio compiler suite comes with a heap-checking utility called `bcheck`. If the Studio compiler suite `man` directory is in your `MANPATH` environment variable, `man bcheck` should be enough to get started.